# Discord.js rename current channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am super new to discord.js, but i'm using a pre-built bot with a ticket system where users do a command to open a ticket.  I want to make it so that only staff, called Faulty Admins in my server, can rename tickets by what they are for by doing -rename .  I could only find this code

```
if(command === `${prefix}openslot`) {

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("#1bc643")
        .setTitle("Sucessfully opened slot for PREMIUM RANK!")
        .addField("Created At", message.author.createdAt)

        .setDescription("SYSTEM");

    message.channel.sendMessage(embed);
message.guild.channels.find("name", "general").setName("Testing");

.then(newChannel => console.log(Channel's new name is ${newChannel.name})) .catch(console.error);

    return;
}
```

online, so im not really sure what to do.  I went digging through the code that came with the bot and this seems to be the code that restricts commands to certain roles

```
if(!message.member.roles.has(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == "Faulty Admins").id)) return message.channel.send('Invalid permissions.');
```

If you have any ideas, please let me know.  It appears that the first code snippet is for changing a spcific channel's name, but I want this command to change the name of the channel that I run the command in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to search for the channel. Just like you can send messages to the same channel using `message.channel.send()`, you can also change the channel similarly:

```js
message.channel.setName("testing")
  .catch(console.error);
```

See [`TextChannel.setName()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setName).

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing some more description and context on why will improve the quality of this answer. Thanks.

Comment: alright ill edit it, I didnt think it was needed since the discord.js library is fairly simple